# "Разваливается" меню при увеличении/уменьшении масштаба окна браузера

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Есть сверстанный макет сайта, на нем меню во всю ширину родительского контейнера. При уменьшении или увеличении масштаба окна браузера меню "разваливается" - последний элемент съезжает на следующую строчку. Как можно исправить и стоит ли вообще на это обращать внимание при верстке?

Comment: ну так код на http://jsfiddle.net залей. не угадывать же нам что там у тебя написано

Comment: или хотя бы сюда код

Comment: Зависит от требований к макету.

Comment: mountpoint, IVsevolod, пробовал, но почему то там эта проблема не появляется...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Задавать ширину элементов меню в процентах
- Задать min-width для контейнера с элементами меню
- Либо жестко прописать размер контейнера и каждого элемента меню

Обращать внимание стоит, так как у всех разрешение экрана разное.. А если ваш сайт ориентирован на мобильные устройства, так тем более... Должно выглядеть везде красиво.

[http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap) - отличный css-фреймворк. Поможет избавиться от таких неприятных мелочей и больше сосредоточиться на функционале, а не на верстке..

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. А поводу css-фреймворка можно поподробней? В чем его смысл? Там пара css и js, что мне с ними делать?

Comment: Смысл в том, что он экономит Ваше время на простых задачах верстки: разметка страницы, создание элементов управления, модальные окна и много-много другого. Все очень просто (если разобраться), быстро а главное - кроссбраузерно.
Лучше всего - полностью прочитать документацию. Если сложно с английским - есть русский вариант http://bootstrap-ru.com/
Прочитав, Вы сами для себя решите стоит ли его использовать на своем проекте или нет. Даже если не будете использовать - знать про него нужно.
Но у русской версии большой недостаток - она уже не актуальна. Поэтому используйте ее лишь для ознакомления